# What's the functional difference between `etree.fromstring()` and `etree.XML()` in lxml?

Tags: python, lxml

[lxml](http://lxml.de/) offers a few different functions to parse strings. Two of them, [`etree.fromstring()`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#fromstring) and [`etree.XML()`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#XML), seem very similar. The docstring for the former says it's for parsing "strings", while the latter "string constants". Additionally, `XML()`'s docstring states:

> This function can be used to embed "XML literals" in Python code, [...]

What's the functional difference between these functions? When should one be used over the other?

Comment: If there is a difference, it makes no difference - see: [Parsing from strings and files](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#parsing-from-strings-and-files). They appear to be exact synonyms, and the only reason I can think of for using `XML()` is that it provides a more readable/explicit name.

Comment: @ekhumoro You can easily [see in the source code](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/82675f9d03a180471056e9fd629e0f13ce4085a1/src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx#L3182-L3231) that they are not exact synonyms. The significance of that difference in `parser` resolution is not immediately obvious, though.

Comment: The source clearly shows that they are *functionally* exact synonyms. That is, if you pass the same (non-`None`) arguments to each function, they will always return exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/master/src/lxml/etree.pyx), for [`XML()`](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/lxml-3.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx#L3167-L3195) and [`fromstring()`](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/lxml-3.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx#L3198-L3216), the former has this extra snippet of code:

```py
if parser is None:
    parser = __GLOBAL_PARSER_CONTEXT.getDefaultParser()
    if not isinstance(parser, XMLParser):
        parser = __DEFAULT_XML_PARSER
```

They thus differ in side effects: `XML()` only uses the default XML parser as the default parser. If the default parser were changed to a non-`XMLParser`, `XML()` will ignore it.

```py
etree.set_default_parser(etree.HTMLParser())
etree.tostring(etree.fromstring("<root/>"))
# b'<html><body><root/></body></html>'
etree.tostring(etree.XML("<root/>"))
# b'<root/>'
```